# how to use another directory in the same folder without using absolute path - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, relative-path, absolute-path

I made a python program using a library called tkinter. I would like to make this program work on Windows but I'm having paths problems. I made a folder called gui that stores images (like icons and buttons), however I can't use images from this folder without putting the entire path

```
from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()
janela.title("lofi-station")
janela.resizable(0,0)
janela.geometry("500x500")
janela.configure(bg='black')
background = PhotoImage(file='/home/myuser/projects/gui/backg1.gif')
janela.option_add('*tearOff',FALSE)
janela.mainloop()
```

I've tried using the relative path but it returns an error. Solving this problem is the key to getting this to work on windows

```
background = PhotoImage(file='./gui/backg1.gif')
```

the return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myuser/projects/lofi_station.py", line 13, in <module>
    background = PhotoImage(file='./gui/backg1.gif')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4038, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "./gui/backg1.gif": no such file or directory
```

after getting this resolved, i want to port this to windows, what would I need to change specifically?

Comment: You need to make sure that the *current working directory* is the same as the script directory.

Comment: Maybe the folder where the python code is executing is not in the `projects` folder.

Comment: You can build the absolute path yourself. Use `os.path.basedir(__file__) + '/gui/backg1.gif''` and check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html how to build pathes that work on Windows, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background = PhotoImage(file=r'./gui/backg1.gif')`

try using this, might help

Comment: This doesn't work if the current working directory is not the same as the directory where this file is stored.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem few months ago. If you are running this code from a python IDE, then you better check the current working directory using `os.getcwd()` importing the module os. The relative path always uses the current working directory. If your cwd is not the expected one then the problem might be that you are on a different folder in your IDE. Just try printing `os.getcwd()` in your code. From my perspective the working directory should be `/home/myuser/projects`. If it prints that you may wanna try this code here:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

janela = Tk()
janela.title("lofi-station")
janela.resizable(0,0)
janela.geometry("500x500")
janela.configure(bg='black')
path = f"{os.getcwd()}/gui/backg1.gif"
background = PhotoImage(file=path)
janela.option_add('*tearOff',FALSE)
janela.mainloop()
```

Maybe the folder where the python code is executing is not in the projects folder. Hopefully, this answer solves your problem.

After resolving this error, you just need to have the same file structure of your project as you had on whatever you had before.